# refresh the updated page after submit

Tags: php

```
<fieldset>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2"><div align="center" class="hed"> Personal Details </div></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>Name:</h3></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h3>DOB</h3></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dob" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $row['dob']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl SET name = ? , dob = ?  WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssi',
$_POST['name'],
$_POST['dob'],
$_REQUEST['id']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

This code works fine but after the update i ve to reload the page to see the result. i tried to create the alert box to reload the page that also dint work and i dont want any action page for the redirection.. how can i reload the page without any action page ?? 
p.s.`onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"` i tried this also dint work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the header in php: [header](https://www.php.net/header). So that the page will get load.

```
<?php
$key = $_GET["id"];  //get your id in $key variable

if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE tbl SET name = ? , dob = ?  WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssi',
$_POST['name'],
$_POST['dob'],
$_REQUEST['id']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
header("Location: yourPageName.php?id=$key"); //call get method here
}
?>
```

Comment: by fetching the id with dat .. its basically a view page redirected by an id

Comment: my id will get lost in the process

Comment: Are you using GET method..? Some thing like : page.php?id=10 ?

Comment: exactly .. i m doing that only

Comment: One more question, can you see that posted id in url of your current page ?

Comment: yes thanks .. i ve tried this one but done a silly  mistk .. so never mind.. thank u again

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line below close line
   If you want same page then

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

If you want redirect to another page then copy below page

```
 header('Location: pageName.php');
```

Comment: the id will get lost in this method.. btw it's been solved

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the exact page you have been on:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```